# Как получить номер текущей записи массива в dot js?

Tags: javascript

```
    {{~it.blogs :value}}
    <br>{{=value.text}}
    {{~}}
```

Допустим выполняется проход по массиву blogs. 
Как получить номер или индекс текущей записи массива при проходе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Это:**

```
{{~it.blogs :value}}
```

**Поменяй на:**

```
{{~it.blogs :value:index}}
```